# Using WireMock and AsyncRestTemplate, how do I test a failure?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, wiremock

I have a client class that uses `AsyncRestTemplate` to make calls to a an http endpoint served by a RestController.

When I use WireMock to test it, it never calls the `onFailure` method.

And when I don't define my own error handler for the rest template, then it hangs forever. (It appears to hang in `okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run`)

If I define my own error handler and return from the `handleError()` method (and don't pass to super's method), then it calls my 'onSuccess' method from the `ListenableFuture`.

How do I get it to call the `onFailure`?

```
@Test
public void testWithInvalidValidRequest() throws Exception
{
    //Setup for the endpoint
    WireMock.stubFor(
        WireMock.post(
            WireMock.urlEqualTo( "/test" )
        )
            .willReturn(
                WireMock.aResponse()
                    .withStatus( 400 )
                    .withBody( "Failed" )
                    .withHeader( "Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString() )
            )
    );

    //Call the endpoint
    ListenableFuture<String> response = clientInterface.getTestResponse( "{}" );

    response.addCallback( new ListenableFutureCallback<T>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(T result)
            {
                completable.complete( result );
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t)
            {
                //This is never called even on debug
                System.out.println("failed");
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

wiremock usage looks correct assuming you have [WireMock rule](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/) specified.

With the code below onFailure works. Due to calls as async you need some timeout or CountDownLatch or other synchronizer to make sure that your test will be run unless your client gets result or fail:

```
ListenableFuture<String> response  = restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, new AsyncRequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void doWithRequest(AsyncClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {

    }
}, new ResponseExtractor<String>() {
    @Override
    public String extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return new Scanner(response.getBody()).useDelimiter("\\A").next() ;
    }
});


response.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
});

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
```